# How to pass class instance to base class constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am having issues with my Transactions in that they are being escalated to a distributed transaction, which I don't want. From what I read, this is caused by opening multiple connections during the scope of the transaction. To correct this, I am re-working my code to be able to create one dbContext and pass it around to all the classes so I only have one context and hence one connection during the scope of the transaction.

My question is, how do I create one instance of the context and pass it to base class. What I posted is what I am trying to do in concept, but obviously that won't work. How can I achieve this?

```
    private WorkOrderHeaderRepository _workOrderHeaderRepository;
    private WorkOrderDetailRepository _workOrderDetailRepository;
    private InventoryMgmtContext _dbContext;

    #region Constructors

    public ManageWorkOrdersAppServ()
        : base(new WorkOrderHeaderRepository(_dbContext )) <----How pass _dbContext to base here
    {
        _dbContext = new InventoryMgmtContext();
        _workOrderHeaderRepository = new WorkOrderHeaderRepository(_dbContext);
        _workOrderDetailRepository = new WorkOrderDetailRepository(_dbContext);

    }
```

Comment: Even if that did work, which it does not, *you'd be passing a null reference*. You haven't initialized the field yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to say what the right thing to do here is but it sounds like you want the context to be a *static field*, not an *instance field*.

```
private static InventoryMgmtContext _dbContext = new InventoryMgmtContext();
public ManageWorkOrdersAppServ()
    : base(new WorkOrderHeaderRepository(_dbContext )) 
{
    _workOrderHeaderRepository = new WorkOrderHeaderRepository(_dbContext);
    _workOrderDetailRepository = new WorkOrderDetailRepository(_dbContext);

}
```

Yes?

The downside here is that the context stays alive forever, which might not be what you want. If that's not what you want then *push the problem off to the caller*:

```
public ManageWorkOrdersAppServ(Context dbContext)
    : base(new WorkOrderHeaderRepository(dbContext )) 
{
    _workOrderHeaderRepository = new WorkOrderHeaderRepository(_dbContext);
    _workOrderDetailRepository = new WorkOrderDetailRepository(_dbContext);

}
```

Make the caller pass in the appropriate context and make them manage its creation.

Also, while we're criticizing this code: .NET stl gdlns frwn on abrvs in nms, thyr hrd 2 rd.  I think you meant to say `InventoryManagementContext`.

Comment: Eric, I appreciate the response. As you will tell from my next question, I am new to c# development and am "home schooled". So what do you mean that it will stay alive forever? The second method is what I am doing now. I just don't like the thought of having to create my context at the controller level and was trying to keep it at the servers layer.

Comment: Ah, no, I don't want the dbContext to last that long. I need to refactor my code a bit. Thanks.