# What is the Lifecycle of a static field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the lifecycle of a static field in C# MVC:

```
private static InventoryMgmtContext _dbContext = new InventoryMgmtContext();
public ManageWorkOrdersAppServ()
    : base(new WorkOrderHeaderRepository(_dbContext )) 
{
    _workOrderHeaderRepository = new WorkOrderHeaderRepository(_dbContext);
    _workOrderDetailRepository = new WorkOrderDetailRepository(_dbContext);

}
```

In this case when does the _dbContext die?
This is a follow up to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263828/how-to-pass-class-instance-to-base-class-constructor) that I haven't been able to get clarification on.

Comment: static fields in web services are truly terrifying

Comment: `DbContext`s shouldn't be `static` anyway, so it's an academic point in this case.

Comment: I suggest you read up on Inversion of Control / Dependency Injection so you don't have to construct your DbContext yourself. You can set it up to create a single context per request and will be available for any of your repositories

Answer (score 9):

Static fields live for as long as the [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) in which the type is loaded lives. That's true regardless of environment.

Now in a web environment, IIS will recycle the `AppDomain` in some situations - so you shouldn't rely on it being the same forever.

If that's really a database context though, I don't think it should be in a static field at all. Typically you create a database context for a single "unit of work".

Comment: Hmmm, that's what I was afraid of. I think I need to refactor my code. I currently have these layers in my app: Controller, Services, Data, and Domain. I am trying to create one instance of the DBContext in the controller layer and pass it all the way down to the other layers to achieve what you are saying...but the way I implemented it, I need to pass the repository, which will take the DB Context in the constructor. So I am having a hard time creating one instance of the Context and sharing that with the current class as well as the inherited one....time to refactor... Thanks Jon.